# How does iptolong work

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, ip

As we all know that long2ip works as ip1.ip2.ip3.ip4 (123.131.231.212)

```
long ip => (ip1 * 256 * 256 * 256) + (ip2 * 256 * 256) + (ip3 * 256) + ip4
2072242132 => (123 * 256 * 256 * 256) + (131 * 256 * 256) + (231 * 256) + 212
```

But what would be pseudo code for converting this number back into an IP address?

Also what would be the most suitable way to store IP addresses in MySQL for a traffic analytics website which will have about over 500 IP lookups per second?

Would it be better if a table with unique IDs is created for every single IP and then that is used for lookups?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent

Comment: You can't demand answers like that. Most if not all of us are here in our own free time and not everyone will be able to come up with an answer quickly.

Comment: I am not demanding an answer. I am asking and telling what is necessary for me but not necessarily for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$long = ip2long("123.131.231.212");

$ip = array();
array_unshift($ip, $long & 0xFF);
array_unshift($ip, ($long >>= 8) & 0xFF);
array_unshift($ip, ($long >>= 8) & 0xFF);
array_unshift($ip, ($long >>= 8) & 0xFF);

// $ip =
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 123
//     [1] => 131
//     [2] => 231
//     [3] => 212
// )
```

Comment: can you please explain what you did there?

Comment: If you're not familiar with bitwise operations, I suggest you [do a little reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).